Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 10622 (unbound) total-vm:325984kB, anon-rss:319528kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:672kB
im seeing the following errors in /var/log/kern.log and im trying to figure out which container it relates too, any idea how i might do this?
May 22 02:54:57 docker-02 kernel: [  235.238815] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 7996 (unbound) total-vm:325660kB, anon-rss:319200kB, file-rss:436kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:676kB oom_score_adj:0 May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [ 
319.934861] unbound invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0 May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [  319.934881] CPU: 2 PID: 9637 Comm: unbound Not tainted 5.15.0-107-generic #117-Ubuntu May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [  319.934991]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x163/0x210 May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [  319.935145] [   9637]  1000  9637    84411    82900   708608        0             0 unbound May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [ 
319.935147] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task=unbound,pid=9637,uid=1000 May 22 02:56:22 docker-02 kernel: [  319.935160] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 9637 (unbound) total-vm:337644kB, anon-rss:331088kB, file-rss:512kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:692kB oom_score_adj:0 May 22 02:58:08 docker-02 kernel: [ 
426.371874]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x163/0x210 May 22 02:58:08 docker-02 kernel: [  426.372001] [  10622]  1000 10622    81496    79882   688128        0             0 unbound May 22 02:58:08 docker-02 kernel: [  426.372005] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task=unbound,pid=10622,uid=1000 May 22 02:58:08 docker-02 kernel: [  426.372032] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 10622 (unbound) total-vm:325984kB, anon-rss:319528kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:672kB oom_score_adj:0 May 22 03:01:10 docker-02 kernel: [ 
608.339423]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x163/0x210 May 22 03:01:10 docker-02 kernel: [  608.339679] [  11146]  1000 11146    78462    76859   671744        0             0 unbound May 22 03:01:10 docker-02 kernel: [  608.339686] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task=unbound,pid=11146,uid=1000 May 22 03:01:10 docker-02 kernel: [  608.339730] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 11146 (unbound) total-vm:313848kB, anon-rss:307428kB, file-rss:8kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:656kB oom_score_adj:0 May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [ 
951.891835] unbound invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0 May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [  951.891858] CPU: 4 PID: 12028 Comm: unbound Not tainted 5.15.0-107-generic #117-Ubuntu May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [  951.891991]  ? page_cache_ra_unbounded+0x163/0x210 May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [  951.892190] [  12028]  1000 12028    84103    82626   716800        0             0 unbound May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [ 
951.892195] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task=unbound,pid=12028,uid=1000 May 22 03:06:54 docker-02 kernel: [  951.892217] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 12028 (unbound) total-vm:336412kB, anon-rss:329956kB, file-rss:548kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:700kB oom_score_adj:0 May 22 03:18:29 docker-02 kernel: [
1647.343477] [  14022]  1000 14022    90047    88472   761856        0             0 unbound May 22 03:18:29 docker-02 kernel: [ 1647.343482] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task_memcg=/system.slice/docker-84650dafae24a54b7e0f98571ee18585495f73a8db3acb1cc8559f0880267d21.scope,task=unbound,pid=14022,uid=1000 May 22 03:18:29 docker-02 kernel: [ 1647.343502] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 14022 (unbound) total-vm:360188kB, anon-rss:353888kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:744kB oom_score_adj:0


Really, there are a lot of good tutorials about OOM and docker available in the Internet. I suggest you do some work.

To debug which container was killed or triggered oom-kill, I usually follow below steps

use docker ps -a or docker container ls --all and see exited containers with exit code 137
see log of systemd which related to oom-kill or docker daemon by using command cat /var/log/syslog | grep memory ,  cat /var/log/syslog | grep killed , maybe you can find container name or something
If you can see some errors in syslog file similar to systemd[1]: docker-dfaa986947499bee10815fe5510de10ba54e24b307c39fee7805e9d18cf9e47e, you can find container with id like using command docker ps -a | grep dfaa

But if system (not dockerd or containerd) killed and deleted container, deleted container will not be shown by using docker ps -a or docker container ls --all
